# How to display the area fully within 5km of a line

Tags: leaflet, gis, turfjs

I am wanting to draw a polygon around a line that shows the area that is **fully within** 5km of the line.

Kind of like a buffer shows the area that is always 5km **away** from a line, I want to show an area that is always **within** 5km of the whole line - so the area will be smaller than the buffer.

The real-life situation is that we now have travel restrictions which in part means you must stay within 5km of your home. So I want to draw an area around a hiking trail - if the person's house is within the area, then they can do the full walk. Part of the issue is I don't even know what this kind of area is called.

Currently using Leaflet and turf like this -- but this is just a masked buffer.

```
                    var mask = turf.polygon([[[90, -55], [170, -55], [170, 10], [90, 10], [90, -55]]]);
                var polygon = turf.mask(turf.buffer(geojsonLines[0], 5, {
                units: 'kilometers'
                }),mask);

                L.geoJSON(polygon, {
                style: function(feature) {
                    return {
                    color: "red"
                    };
                }
                }).addTo(journey_map);
```

(not how I will deal with tracks that extend more than 5km from a BBOX -- but will deal with that).
[Image of buffer area similar to what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRmEy.jpg)

Comment: You're so close, pal, so close. https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right that you want area within 5km of **every** point in a shape, rather than buffer which is area within 5km of **any** point in a shape?

If so, I don't know of an existing operation to compute this or how it is called, but it seems easy to compute.

If you look at a line segment [A, B] and distance from any point C on this segment to some distant point D, it is easy to see `CD` is less than or equal to `max(AD, BD)`. So if D is within 5km from corners A and B, it is within 5km of all points on AB. Same for a triangle - points within 5km of all points in triangle should be within 5km of each corner of triangle.

This leads to simple (although probably not very efficient) algorithm: take all vertices in the linestring describing a trail or polygon describing a park, buffer each of them by 5km separately and intersect all the resulting circles (https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect). The result of intersection is within 5km of each vertex, and thus within 5km of all points in trail.

A simple optimization you do is first compute convex hull of the shape - this would simplify a typical trail, reducing the number of vertices, and the number of circles you need to intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael
got it :)
I ended up doing the intersect of the buffer of each point (rather than line segment) as there are so many points on my lines that will work -- but line segments would be more complete. Nice. This I the code using leaflet and turf.

```
var travel_radius = 5;
                var simplify_options = {tolerance: 0.01, highQuality: false};
                var exploded = turf.explode(turf.simplify(geojsonLines[0],simplify_options));
                var intersection = turf.intersect(turf.buffer(exploded['features'][0]['geometry'], travel_radius, {units: 'kilometers'}), turf.buffer(exploded['features'][1]['geometry'], travel_radius, {units: 'kilometers'}));
                
                var i = 2;
                while (i < exploded['features'].length ) {
                    if(intersection == null){break;} // for walks that are bigger than the travel radius -- result will get to null
                    intersection = turf.intersect(intersection, turf.buffer(exploded['features'][i]['geometry'], travel_radius, {units: 'kilometers'}));
                                i++;
                                }

                if(intersection == null){ // just draw a small circle at the start so the rest of the map is red. 
                    intersection = turf.buffer(exploded['features'][0]['geometry'], 5, {units: 'meters'});
                }

                // subtract travel area from the mask
                var mask = turf.polygon([[[90, -55], [170, -55], [170, 10], [90, 10], [90, -55]]]);
                var polygon = turf.mask(intersection,mask);

                L.geoJSON(polygon, {
                style: function(feature) {
                    return {
                    color: "red"
                    };
                }
                }).addTo(journey_map);
            });
```